# Setting Heroku debug rails runner

Tags: ruby, debugging, heroku

I'm new to coding and have been working on an app following and outdated tutorial. I have managed to fix every error message on my Heroku log when I push my ruby app through. The app still pops up an error message when I run it on the heroku servers and the log still gives me this error warning message:

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
remote: 
remote:
```

I cant find where I'm suppose to make this change or even know what this would do. I have a feeling that it's a simple solution but I cant figure it out.

This is what my heroku log is currently showing

```
2018-12-15T17:21:34.785786+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-12-15T17:21:34.785794+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:58573
2018-12-15T17:21:34.785800+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-12-15T17:21:34.785802+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2018-12-15T17:21:34.785804+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-12-15T17:38:25.438993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-garden-52262.herokuapp.com request_id=a4f35efc-e682-4350-b203-f6fc40c56b1b fwd="70.112.41.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-12-15T17:38:26.735908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-garden-52262.herokuapp.com request_id=9385f6b6-5d5f-4103-a3f3-68f9ebd25dd5 fwd="70.112.41.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-12-15T17:43:54.026844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 25147`
2018-12-15T17:43:59.063571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-15T17:43:59.038449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-12-15T17:43:58.930540+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
2018-12-15T17:43:58.930556+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962749+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962817+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962842+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962866+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962891+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962927+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962951+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.962979+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963031+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 8203 levels...
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963066+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963101+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963127+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.963152+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-12-15T17:43:58.967298+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-12-15T17:43:58.967317+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25147
2018-12-15T17:43:58.967320+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-12-15T17:43:58.967321+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2018-12-15T17:43:58.967323+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-12-15T18:05:03.958347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-15T18:05:03.729401+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0386a188 by user jlacayorb@gmail.com
2018-12-15T18:05:03.729401+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user jlacayorb@gmail.com
2018-12-15T18:05:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-12-15T18:05:08.805116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 8502`
2018-12-15T18:05:14.925692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-15T18:05:14.931749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-15T18:05:14.905651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-12-15T18:05:14.726237+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
2018-12-15T18:05:14.726365+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
2018-12-15T18:05:14.727118+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You did not specify a `log_level` in `production.rb`. Currently, the default value for `log_level` is `:info` for the production environment and `:debug` in all other environments. In Rails 5 the default value will be unified to `:debug` across all environments. To preserve the current setting, add the following line to your `production.rb`:
2018-12-15T18:05:14.727121+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-15T18:05:14.727122+00:00 app[web.1]: config.log_level = :info
2018-12-15T18:05:14.727124+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-15T18:05:14.727126+00:00 app[web.1]: . (called from block in tsort_each at /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228)
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797162+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797240+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797267+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797291+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797312+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797348+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797384+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797405+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797447+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 8205 levels...
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797468+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797488+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797548+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.797572+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-12-15T18:05:14.801727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-12-15T18:05:14.801731+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:8502
2018-12-15T18:05:14.801733+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-12-15T18:05:14.801734+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2018-12-15T18:05:14.801736+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-12-15T18:05:20.094258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 35401`
2018-12-15T18:05:25.100044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-15T18:05:25.077419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-12-15T18:05:58.745553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-garden-52262.herokuapp.com request_id=6ebfcd29-1a92-4fd1-ba7b-0d4216003aba fwd="70.112.41.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-12-15T18:11:27.532952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-15T18:11:26.693865+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user jlacayorb@gmail.com
2018-12-15T18:11:26.693865+00:00 app[api]: Set LOG_LEVEL config vars by user jlacayorb@gmail.com
2018-12-15T18:11:31.039288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 41715`
2018-12-15T18:11:35.076811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-12-15T18:11:34.942902+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
2018-12-15T18:11:34.942925+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
2018-12-15T18:11:34.944782+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You did not specify a `log_level` in `production.rb`. Currently, the default value for `log_level` is `:info` for the production environment and `:debug` in all other environments. In Rails 5 the default value will be unified to `:debug` across all environments. To preserve the current setting, add the following line to your `production.rb`:
2018-12-15T18:11:34.944785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-15T18:11:34.944787+00:00 app[web.1]: config.log_level = :info
2018-12-15T18:11:34.944788+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-15T18:11:34.944790+00:00 app[web.1]: . (called from block in tsort_each at /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228)
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002089+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002096+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002098+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002100+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002102+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002103+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002105+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002106+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002108+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002110+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 8201 levels...
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002112+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002116+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002117+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.002119+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-12-15T18:11:35.005242+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-12-15T18:11:35.005245+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41715
2018-12-15T18:11:35.005247+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-12-15T18:11:35.005248+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2018-12-15T18:11:35.005250+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
```

Anything helps!

Comment: You probably have to do this config in the Heroku environment variable settings – not in the app itself.

Comment: I tried adding this command under the heroku/master file but that didn't work. is that what you mean?

Comment: `(2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` This appears every time the server shuts down. Might want to check your code to see what is causing it.

Comment: [This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) explains the various ways that you can set environment variables on Heroku. Add a new var for `HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER` and set its value to `1`.

Comment: Just run `heroku config:set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1` when you have the heroku tools installed.

Comment: hey everyone, thank you for all your help. I have done so much to the code I am lost and getting all kinds of different error. Your suggestions did help me solve that specific problem though so thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This was answered in the comments above, it worked for me:

```
heroku config:set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1
```

Comment: I tried this, and it did set the variable, but I am getting the following message: ```Warning: The "HEROKU_" namespace is protected and shouldn't be used```, so what is the proper way to handle this?  Also what is the purpose of this config variable?

Comment: I'll keep looking, but getting the same response as @Obromios. Rails 7.0.0, Ruby 3.0.2